# How to avoid unavailability of data while table is being truncated and populated

Tags: mysql, data-structures

I'm comparing a mysql table with a sybase table, both having the same exact table definitions.

My script selects all from the sybase table, truncates everything that's in the mysql table, and re-populates the mysql table with that data.

The reason I truncate the table is because some records might have been deleted from the sybase one by the time the script runs again.

There is no way I can find out which record has been deleted, so I just truncate the mysql table, and populate it all over again (which doesn't seem to be a wise strategy).

This causes two issues (at least two):

one that users experience unavailable data if they try to access mysql while it's getting truncated and populated,

and two, as the size of tables are growing, this process will be costly.

some information about the tables:

> no primary keys
>
> a two-column unique key (used for indexing)

What other options (data structure wise) do I have other than truncating the table?

if truncating can be an option, how can I prevent the unavailability of data?

Comment: Incidentally, in a strict RDBMS sense, if you don't have a PRIMARY KEY then you don't really have a table.

Comment: If you have a unique key, you can make that the primary key.

Comment: @Barmar how would that help me if I do that?

Comment: It makes no real difference. @Strawberry was just being pedantic.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

1. Load the data into a new table
2. Rename the original table to a temporary name.
3. Rename the new table to the original table's name.
4. Drop the table with the temporary name.

Steps 2 and 3 will be very quick, so there should be a very short window when the table is unavailable.

Comment: Tip: You can do multiple renames in one RENAME TABLE statement, and these are executed atomically, so you can avoid even an instant of unavailability.

Comment: this solution is great, but wouldn't work for me because we have a backup process that will fail if any DDL statements are run during the process, and I just realized that.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is having two tables with the same structure, one empty, one full with data.

The latter one is used by your application, while the former one will be filled with data from the sybase table in the background. Once the data transfer is completed, the application starts using the table with the fresh data and you can truncate the table with the old data.

Comment: This means all the queries in the application will have to be constructed dynamically with the name of the currently active table. And that state will have to be stored somewhere.